# TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation (except: ^)

Tags: python, tweepy

I have a code like as below.. but there is something wrong in my main code.. Anyone can help me to spot the problem... I am literally stuck at this indentation error... It says there is indentation error occurered at `except:` in the main function...

```
import tweepy
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import csv

def get_all_tweets(screen_name):

    consumer_key = *
    consumer_secret = *
    access_key = *
    access_secret = *

    #authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)


    noRT = []

    search_terms = 'superbowl ', 'super bowl ', '#superbowl'


    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,
        screen_name = screen_name,
        tweet_mode="extended",
        wait_on_rate_limit=True,
        include_retweets=False,
        count=100).pages(20):
            for status in page:
                noRT.append([status.id_str, status.created_at, status.full_text.encode("utf-8")])
                
            # do your process on status

    with open('{}_tweets.csv'.format(screen_name), 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text"])
        writer.writerows(noRT)
        print('{}_tweets.csv was successfully created.'.format(screen_name))
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    usernames = ["GregoryBlakley","Minihova","TheAMRCentre","throse_gd","CDCgov","TheAMRCentre","GuyFema","EndGameWW3","ABC","Childishnegrit0","WorldPeace24_7","byetofi","mumabear13"]
    for x in usernames:
        try: 
            get_all_tweets(x)
        except:
            print "%s does not exist" % (twitter_id)
            pass
```

What's wrong with this code?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    usernames = ["GregoryBlakley","Minihova","TheAMRCentre","throse_gd","CDCgov","TheAMRCentre","GuyFema","EndGameWW3","ABC","Childishnegrit0","WorldPeace24_7","byetofi","mumabear13"]
    for x in usernames:
        try: 
            get_all_tweets(x)
        except:
            print "%s does not exist" % (twitter_id)
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing tabs and spaces inside your `for` loops, e.g.:

[image: example of mixed tabs and spaces from code in question]

Python 3 disallows mixing the use of tabs and spaces for indentation.